# Unable to render a color cube

Tags: c, opengl, graphics, 3d

I am trying to draw a color cube in OpenGL. All I am getting is a square.
(Is only one face of the cube visible in the output? I tried calling gluLookAt(), but that didn't make any difference to the output.)

This is my code:

```
#include<GL/glut.h>

#include<math.h>

float vertices[8][3]={{0,0,0},{0,0,200},{0,200,0},{200,0,0},{0,200,200},{200,0,200},{200,200,0},{200,200,200}};

float colors[8][3]={{0.6,0.9,0.1},{0.2,0.1,0.3},{0.7,0.7,0.5},{0.2,0.7,0.4},{0.6,0.6,0.4},{0.1,0.1,0.5},{0.7,0.2,0.5},{0.9,0.7,0.4}};

void display()

{

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3fv(colors[0]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[0]);
        glColor3fv(colors[2]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[2]);
        glColor3fv(colors[5]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[5]);
        glColor3fv(colors[1]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[1]);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3fv(colors[0]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[0]);
        glColor3fv(colors[3]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[3]);
        glColor3fv(colors[6]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[6]); 
        glColor3fv(colors[2]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[2]);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3fv(colors[1]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[1]);
        glColor3fv(colors[4]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[4]);
        glColor3fv(colors[7]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[7]);
        glColor3fv(colors[5]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[5]);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3fv(colors[4]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[4]);
        glColor3fv(colors[3]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[3]);
        glColor3fv(colors[6]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[6]);
        glColor3fv(colors[7]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[7]);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3fv(colors[2]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[2]);
        glColor3fv(colors[6]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[6]);
        glColor3fv(colors[7]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[7]);
        glColor3fv(colors[5]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[5]);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glColor3fv(colors[0]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[0]);
        glColor3fv(colors[3]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[3]);
        glColor3fv(colors[4]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[4]);
        glColor3fv(colors[1]);
        glVertex3fv(vertices[1]);
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
}

void init()
{

        glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0);
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glOrtho(-960,960,-720,720,-600,600);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

        glutInit(&argc, argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB|GLUT_DEPTH);
        glutInitWindowSize(960,720);
        glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
        glutCreateWindow("Color Cube");
        glutDisplayFunc(display);
        init();
        glutMainLoop();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are requesting a double-buffered framebuffer via the `GLUT_DOUBLE` flag. So you have a back buffer you are drawing into, and a front buffer which is shown in the window. When you are finished with drawing, you have to swap those buffers so that the things you have drawn now become visible and you can draw the next frame (without destroying the currently visible image). Just replace that `glFlush();` at the end of your `display()` function by a `glutSwapBuffers()` call and your rendering should become visible.

Comment: And that is the correct output for your code. What do you expect? You do see one side of the cube, as you should.

Comment: What should I do if I want to see more than 1 side, i.e., change the camera angle so that more than 1 side is visible?

Comment: use gluLookAt and glPerspective or glOrtho(orthographic projection) to set up your camera. http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm you see only one face because they left unchanged, so they're identity matrices. PS. for better control use glm library and load your own matrices

Answer (score 0):

Try using push and pop matrix
ex.

```
glPushMatrix();
//your cube's code
glPopMatrix();
glFlush();
```

Comment: Still no change to the output.

Comment: try adding the depth test in the main method
 glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

Comment: i remember having such a problem..but it was long time ago :?
so it seems i can't remember it right..sry

Comment: @OmarElshal: Adding those matrix stack operations is completely pointless in his currenct code, as he never modifies the matrices anyways.

Comment: you r absolutely right, that was the first thing came to my mind when i saw his question..my bad sry :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see more than 1 side of your cube, you will need to rotate your cube.

Look up the `glRotate()` function, which multiplies the current matrix by a rotation.  Applying this rotation (*before* drawing the cube) will effectively rotate your cube by a given angle, about the specified axis.